# user_login view not functioning properly

Tags: django

Am able to register users successfully in my register view,however when i try to login using those credentials in the user_login view,am redirected to a page that says my credentials are wrong.whats the problem ? Here is the code.

user_login view

```
def user_login(request):


if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')


    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


    if user is not None:

        if user.is_active:
            .
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("your acc was disabled")
    else:

        print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
        return HttpResponse('Invalid login details')
else:

    return render(request,'login.html', {})
```

login template
    
    
        Rango

```
<body>
    <h1>Login to Rango</h1>

    <form id = "login_form" method = "post" action = "/rango/login/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Username: <input type = "text" name = "username" value="" size="50"/>
        <br/>
        Password: <input type = "password" name = "username" value="" size="50"/>
        <br/>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong name for your password input. It should be:

```
Password: <input type = "password" name = "password" value="" size="50"/>
```